# Cannot add systemd-analyze to Buildroot image

Tags: systemd, embedded, buildroot

I decided to use systemd in my embedded linux system to be able to use systemd-analyze tool. I can add both systemd and systemd-analyze in my config, but after runing my system on Raspberry Pi 4, I can't run `systemd-analyze` (command not found). Do I need to add something else to make this work or configure something?

Moreover, when I type `systemctl status` or similar command, I see that

Comment: You probably didn't change `$PATH`?

Comment: Do you mean field `Set the system's default PATH: /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`?

Comment: Where are the binaries `systemd-analyze` and `systemctl` located on your system?

Comment: `systemctl` is in `/sbin/systemctl`, `/usr/bin/systemctl`. I can't find systemd-analyze, but I marked it to install

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63576707/1025638) and I suggested [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67906157/1025638).

To sum-up, rebuild the `systemd` package to re-apply the configuration:

```
make systemd-dirclean
make
```